# Regex match for curly braces with equals sign in them

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, curly-braces

I need a regex to match for things such as:

```
{RandomName Option="value"}
{AnotherRandomString AnotherOption="Another value" Option1="Woot woot"}
```

Basically, anything where it begins with a { and random string, followed by a space, then a list of name-value sorts of pairs with and = sign and quotations around the value. The furthest I've been able to get so far is below, but it's not very close I don't think:

```
preg_match_all(
        '#\{(.*?)\=(.*?)\}#ims',
        $this->search_string,
        $the_matches
    );
```

Comment: [RegexPal](http://www.regexpal.com) is such a great resource. It even has a handy "cheat sheet" and you can put strings in to test your regex. Try playing around on that for a bit before you try to get too fancy with other people's regex that you modify, etc.

Comment: What's the problem, your regex matches what you expect it to. Do you want it to be more specific?

Comment: More specific would be nice because after dumping the array it appears to have a bunch of empty arrays inside of it and gets things like "{sting} <li class=", too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a better regex to match your case more specifically:

```
#\{[^{}]+\=[^{}]+\}#ims
```

This assumes that there will never be a close brace `}` inside.

**Edit** adding an exception for `{` as well.

Comment: Is there a way to make it such that if a { or a } appears anywhere than at the beginning and end, it doesn't match?

Comment: That's what this regex does. `[^ ]` means none of the char inside.

Comment: In my testing, it is matching: {module:list id="{listId} ... The second { in there before the } should cause it to not match, no?

Comment: Oh. I understand, the solution (in my edit now) is `[^{}]`, meaning not `{` and not `}`

Comment: matches but does not break the values down only finds the whole string

Answer (score 1):

How about this? It creates one numbered group for the starting label, one for all the name/value pairs, and then one for each separate name/value pair.

```
{(\w+)\s+((\w+=".*?"\s*)+)}
```

Comment: That's good, but it also grabs all sorts of HTML elements in the string I'm looking through.